# Binding A Media Feed/ Stream to Video Element - Vue 3 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, video-streaming, html5-video, vuejs3

I am trying to bind a camera feed to a video element using Vue 3, but I can not seem to even get a basic example working. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

```js
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
let stream: any = reactive({})
let constraints = {
    audio: false,
    video: {
      width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
      height: { min: 576, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
      facingMode: 'environment'
    }
  }
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
```

---

Then in my template I have tried both of the following ways to bind

```html
<video :srcObject.prop="stream" width="300" height="200" autoplay></video>
<video :srcObject.prope.camel="stream" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code overwrites `stream` with the result of `getUserMedia()`, which effectively removes the original `reactive()` instance from the component's context.

### Solution

Make `stream` a `ref` instead of `reactive`, and set its `value` property to the result of `getUserMedia()`.

Also, to ensure the user's resources are activated only when necessary, call `getUserMedia()` in the component's `mounted` hook, and stop the stream in the `beforeUnmount` hook.

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue'

const stream = ref(null)
const constraints = {
  audio: false,
  video: {
    width: { min: 1024, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
    height: { min: 576, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
    facingMode: 'environment',
  },
}

onMounted(async () => {
  stream.value = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
})

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  stream.value.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
})
</script>

<template>
  <video :srcObject="stream" width="300" height="200" autoplay></video>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-get-user-media?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyCameraVideo.vue)

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. See updated demo link.